# How to draw vector as input

Tags: logic-gates, boolean-algebra

I have implemented a function f which takes as input 4 digits vector, how could I draw that correctly?
I know how to draw a function with 4 inputs but not one with vector on inputs.

An image could be really useful. Thanks

Comment: This question should be more relevant in the math stackexchange. Questions to be clarified: what is the dimension of your codomain? Could you present the exact function? What resources will you have available to present this - e.g. would some kind of animation suffice, or does it have to be printable?

Comment: @VicenteCunha I want to draw the function as a box, and to draw it on paper just a sketch of how input vector would look like

Comment: Two common forms: 1) line with a forward slash in the middle, with the width (4) as a label above the slash; 2) label with the bit range, i.e. [3:0] on top of the line.